# OpenCL - For Loops and Relationship with GlobalWorkSize

Tags: arrays, loops, opencl

While reading over some code I had a couple of questions that popped into my head.

Let's assume we had a globalWorkSize of one million elements in an array.

Assume the purpose of the kernel was to simply take summation of 100 elements at a time and store these values in an output. Ex) First time the kernel would sum elements 0-99, then it would do 1-100, then 2-101 and so on. All the summed values get stored in an array.

Now we know that there are 1 million elements, when we pass this to clEnqueueNDRangeKernel, does that mean the kernel will execute close to one million times?

I noticed that the for loop in the kernel only loops to one hundred elements, then the value is just stored in another array. So by just examining the for loop, one would just think that after 100 elements it would stop. How does the computer know when we have reached 1 million elements? Is it because we passed the parameter in clEnqueueNDRangeKernel and at an atomic level it knows that more elements need to be processed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The device has no way to know that there are one million elements in the array. So if you set the global_work_size to be one million the last 99 kernels will happily overindex the array which may or may not seg fault depending on the device.

When you call the clEnqueueNDRangeKernel API call with a worksize of N then the information is sent to the device and the device will execute anough uniform sized workgroups untill it has executed the kernel N times.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Yes it does thank you. I just was caught in a moment yesterday where I didn't understand how the kernel could possibly finish all the elements. This answer makes it more clear.